# browserSync not working

Tags: node.js, gulp, browser-sync

I have this code to reload the browser with any change:

```
var gulp          = require('gulp');
var browserSync   = require('browser-sync');

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./"
        }
    });

});
```

I'm triggering browserSync here, through html.js:

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var fileinclude = require('gulp-file-include');
var rename      = require('gulp-rename');
var util        = require('gulp-util');

gulp.task('html', function() {

    var filename = 'middle.html';

    return gulp.src(filename)
        .pipe(fileinclude())
        .pipe(rename('index.html'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}));
});
```

For some reason, html.js seems to work (fileinclude, rename, etc... is done) but browserSync doesn't. I don't get any error message, but the browser does not reload automatically. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you got the Browsersync Javascript in your html?

Comment: No, I have it in a separate file (browserSync.js) in the tasks folder, same as html.js

Comment: If you load the page in the browser, can you find the browsersync javascript tag? It should be something like this: `document.write("<script async src='/browser-sync/browser-sync-client.1.7.2.js'><\/script>".replace(/HOST/g, location.hostname).replace(/PORT/g, location.port));`

Comment: No, nothing like that. Is it something a should add to the HTML? Thanks

Comment: It should be placed there automaticaly by browsersync. Are you using browserSync as your server as well?

Comment: Yes, I am. That part is working properly, the server works, it just doesn't update properly.

Comment: How do you call the task? Do you have a watch task or something similar? Is the browser-sync task called when the html is called (ie is the configuration loaded?)

Comment: Do you see a "Connected to BrowserSync" message in the top right-hand-side of your browser when the page first loads? Check here https://github.com/shakyShane/browser-sync#requirements

Comment: 1. Yes, I use watch for that. That is actually working. 2. No, I don't get the message. It seems everything works (build, watch, other code in html.js...) but not the browserSync. I used gup-notify in a pipe AFTER the browserSync pipe and it was working.

Comment: Can you post your watch task as well? Maybe it is the order of the subtasks that is the problem. Eg. if the configureation is loaded after the html task (or not at all).

Comment: Here it is. I tried to include many things lately to be sure that was not the problem: var gulp   = require('gulp');

gulp.task('watch', function() {

 // watch for changes to html
 gulp.watch([
  'html/*'
 ], ['html']);
 gulp.watch([
  '*.html'
 ], ['html']);
 gulp.watch([
  'js/*'
 ], ['html']);
 gulp.watch([
  'css/*'
 ], ['html']);


 // watch for changes to sass
 gulp.watch([
  'css/*',
 ], ['sass']);

});

Comment: Do you have a <body> tag present in the html file? That was the problem for me when starting a new project.

Answer (score 3):

Below technique worked for me.

For Automatic Reloading of

- **Html** you should use **browserSync.reload**
- and for **CSS** use **browserSync.stream()**.

```html
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');

var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create(); // for live-editing

gulp.task('default', function(){

 // Serve files from the root of this project
 browserSync.init({
      server: "./"
 });
 
 gulp.watch('sass/**/*.scss', ['styles']);

 //-----*****   RELOADING of HTML   *****-----
 gulp.watch("*.html").on("change", browserSync.reload);
 
});


gulp.task('styles', function(){

 gulp.src('sass/**/*.scss')
 
 .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))      
 
  .pipe( gulp.dest('./css'))

 //-----*****   RELOADING of CSS   *****-----
 .pipe(browserSync.stream()); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm not 100% sure if this is the issue, but try this. Add the browser-sync task to the watch task, to load the configuration.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
gulp.task('watch', ['browser-sync'], function() { // Add your browser-sync task to the watch task
    gulp.watch([ 'html/*' ], ['html']);
    gulp.watch([ '.html' ], ['html']);
    gulp.watch([ 'js/' ], ['html']);
    gulp.watch([ 'css/*' ], ['html']);
    gulp.watch([ 'css/*', ], ['sass']);
});
```

And then amend your browser-sync configuration to inject css changes into the browser:

```
var gulp          = require('gulp');
var browserSync   = require('browser-sync');

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./",
            injectChanges: true // this is new
        }
    });

});
```

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Still nothing, but thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Let us know if you find it out, I'm curious.